# Wrong HTML5 email validation with new domain names

Tags: validation, email, dns

I'm using an standard HTML5 email address validation, but I get error for new domain "technology" (test@mycustomer.technology) 
I ve tried to modify the pattern, but I still get email error

My code

```
<input pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL ADRESS" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That pattern looks ok, https://regex101.com/r/pjcY4j/1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the slashes at the start and end of the pattern. Used when doing RegEx in javascript, it is not required when specifying the `pattern` in html5 elements:

```html
<form>
<input pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL ADRESS" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```